# Rails source: Where SQL queries are designed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking through the Ruby on Rails Active Record source code in search for the place SQL is generated, but I can't find it.  Since Active Record converts methods such as *Person.first* to an Oracle, MySQL or Sql Server query, I figured it would be in the Active Record folder.  I have looked for days, but I can't find the place these queries are generated.

Where can I find the actual query generation?

Comment: Search here: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters

Comment: AR uses Arel to build its queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord uses Arel for SQL generation. The source for `Arel::Visitors::ToSql` is where most of the SQL is generated.

You can find it on Github here:

https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb